# nodejs express app serve static files from public/js folder not work

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I am developing a nodejs express project.

In the project there is a public folder with many subfolders like js, css, images etc.
Originally serving files from these folders was using this code:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

All requested files can be served by the server using this, but files in the js folder not found by the server. If I change the folde name from 'js' to somthing else then it works.

So for example this not found by server if the requested url is /js/work/work.js:

```
app.use('/js',express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public/js')));
```

but this is found if requested url is /asd/work/work.js:

```
app.use('/asd',express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public/asd')));
```

Earlier I was using Mac and Windows for development but now I switched to Ubuntu and then happed this strange thing.

Comment: Could there be a file permission issue on your server in `public/js` such that `express.static()` can't access the files in that particular directory and thus doesn't see them?

Comment: Or do you have some other middleware hooked up to `/js` so the request isn't getting to your `express.static()` middleware?

Comment: I started to rename files and resave files that was downloaded from the repo and some of them is ok now. Maybe there is something problem with the file system or encoding...?

Comment: I think the problem is that in the scripts src property url folder name is not starting with capital letter but the folder nam is capitalized. So the folder is 'Work' and the src is '/js/work/work.js'. If I change '/js/Work/work.js' it resolves that. Is this caused by different operating systems?

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu would be a case sensitive file system and Windows would not be case sensitive.  Best to use lowercase only for filenames and URLs in a web system.

Answer (score 1):

### **1. Add this middleware in the `index.js` above you set view engine**

```
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
```

### **2. Folder Structure**

```
|__public/   
    |__ css/
        |__ css files...
    |__ js/
        |__ js files...
```

**3. Import this way**

Now you set the path to the public directory you have to give the path public folder when you import

```
//For CSS File
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css" />

//For JS File
<script src="/js/script.js"></script>
```

## **You should now be all set up to access CSS or any file**